# How to move closure to struct field?

Tags: rust, ownership

I have this non-working snippet of rust code:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct Sortable<T> {
    buffer: Vec<T>,
    compare: Box<dyn Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering>,
}

impl<T> Sortable<T> {
    fn new(compare_func: impl Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering) -> Sortable<T> {
        Sortable {
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            compare: Box::new(compare_func),
        }
    }

    fn sort(&mut self) {
        self.buffer.sort_by(&self.compare);
    }
}
```

The compiler throw this error:

```
the parameter type `impl Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering` may not live long enough
```

I thought parameter `compare_func` will move from caller to function `new` then to struct field `compare`, since there is no reference (`&`) in function declaration. But somehow the error is about lifetime problem. Am I doing something wrong here, or there are some workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, whenever you have a reference type inside the definition of another type, the borrowing rules require explicit annotation of lifetimes to ensure the correctness of references. When using function pointers or closures directly inside a struct, Rust needs to know how long the references to these functions will be valid to ensure safety. This is where explicit lifetime annotations become crucial.

an alternative solution would be passing lifetime parameter

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct Sortable<'a, T> {
    buffer: Vec<T>,
    compare: Box<dyn Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T> Sortable<'a, T> {
    fn new(compare_func: impl Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering + 'a) -> Sortable<'a, T> {
        Sortable {
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            compare: Box::new(compare_func),
        }
    }

    fn sort(&mut self) {
        self.buffer.sort_by(&self.compare);
    }
}
```

Lifetime parameter `'a` describes the lifetime of the references held by the Sortable struct. The 'a lifetime parameter is applied to the compare field, indicating that the closure stored in compare has a lifetime that is at least as long as the Sortable struct itself.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by requiring that the closure have a static lifetime. This reflects the lifetime requirements of the struct in the function signature.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct Sortable<T> {
    buffer: Vec<T>,
    // Since a lifetime is not specified, this type is inferred to be
    // Box<dyn 'static + Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering>
    compare: Box<dyn Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering>,
}

impl<T> Sortable<T> {
    fn new(compare_func: impl Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering + 'static) -> Sortable<T> {
        Sortable {
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            compare: Box::new(compare_func),
        }
    }

    fn sort(&mut self) {
        self.buffer.sort_by(&self.compare);
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d979de521098c77bdb84953b258201f).

Comment: Isn't that by using static lifetime specifier, the closure created won't be freed for the lifetime of the program? So, won't create and free Sortable instance multiple times will create memory leak, since the closure never cleaned up?

Comment: @AtpurRafif No. Here `'static` refers to the lifetime of _captured variables_ by the closure. If closure passed to `new` would capture by reference some variable with lifetime `'a`, then it also would have to have a lifetime of `'a` (even after boxing), but your struct signature doesn't say anything about it. Saying that closure is `'static` is basically saying that this closure does not capture anything by reference. It will be freed normally when `Box` is dropped however, just like anything else. There is no leak.

Comment: So the the closure function itself won't take any space in runtime memory, but it's like string literal, defined and live in binary. Only *captured variables* that will take that space there. Is there any reference where I can read more about this?